# How to create a comment in TFS for releases?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Is there a way or a tool to force users to write a comment to TFS every time a release of a project is created?

I am searching for something similar to the comments that are input when a file has been checked in to TFS, only for releases instead.

We are having a hard time keeping track of the changes made each time a new release is deployed and I imagine this would be a huge help in keeping track.  I am currently using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: TFS Build can label the source control version it pulled from. There is also an AssemblyVersion activity that can version stamp the compiled assemblies so you can track them better. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jjameson/?p=584

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a release management solution, so you can automate and track your software as it's delivered through a pipeline from your dev environments up through to production environments.

You didn't specify what version of TFS you're using, but if you're using TFS 2013 or earlier, you can use the [Release Management server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/release/rm-for-vs2015-vs). This software is being deprecated, however, so I wouldn't recommend starting out with it now unless you have absolutely no other choice.

In TFS 2015 Update 2, there is a [fully integrated release management hub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/release/overview) in TFS. This would be the recommended approach.